# How to test CheckboxSelectMultiple in save

Tags: django, forms, checkbox

I have a form (`ModelForm`) in Django, where I am adding a field for users in the init method as so:

```
self.fields["users"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=users, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False,label="Add Designer(s)"
)
```

In the `save` method how I can iterate over the queryset for this field, however, I do not know how I can test if the particular model has been selected/checked. Help, please.

EDIT:
Let's say that you have a form where you want to be able to add users to a certain project, I set the users field as above (also used`MultipleChoiceField`) but my real question is how do you determine the state of those checkboxes (which users should be added)?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it using MultipleChoiceField instead of ModelMultipleChoiceField. Then populated the choices with existing event IDs and passed it to the template.
In forms:

```
choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

In views:

```
form.fields['choices'].choices = [(x.eventID, "Event ID: " + x.eventID) for x in unapproved]
```

Had to change some of the logic for finding and editing Event objects too.

Comment: Thanks! Changing to MultipleChoiceField presents me with the same issue, I updated my original post

Answer (score 0):

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) states that a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` normalizes to a QuerySet of model instances. That means in your example, it will only return the users that have been checked. If none have been checked, it will return an empty QuerySet.

If you are overriding your ModelForm `save` method, you could include something like this:

```py
selected_users = self.cleaned_data.get('users')
for user in selected_users:
    project_users.add(user)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it still returns all users, regardless of if they are selected or not.

Comment: @user1314147 - That's odd. I've done some tests to confirm that it should work correctly. How are you checking what it returns?